# What is the sequence of actions at a recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, nested, mergesort

I am trying to understand a merge sort algorithm java code but I really stuck at the splitting phase. Full code is here:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArray = { 20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22 };

        mergeSort(intArray, 0, intArray.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
        }
    }

    // { 20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22 }
    public static void mergeSort(int[] input, int start, int end) {

        if (end - start < 2) {
            return;
        }

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(input, start, mid);
        mergeSort(input, mid, end);
        merge(input, start, mid, end);
    }

    // { 20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22 }
    public static void merge(int[] input, int start, int mid, int end) {

        if (input[mid - 1] <= input[mid]) {
            return;
        }

        int i = start;
        int j = mid;
        int tempIndex = 0;

        int[] temp = new int[end - start];
        while (i < mid && j < end) {
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[i] <= input[j] ? input[i++] : input[j++];
        }

        System.arraycopy(input, i, input, start + tempIndex, mid - i);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, input, start, tempIndex);
    }
}
```

At the following `mergeSort` method:

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] input, int start, int end) {

    if (end - start < 2) {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    mergeSort(input, start, mid);
    mergeSort(input, mid, end);
    merge(input, start, mid, end);
}
```

there are two recursive calls to `mergeSort` and one `merge` call, so what is the sequence of actions at this method and how splitting could be done without any extra variables for keeping divided unsorted data?

Comment: On the whole the methods will execute in the order that they are written in in the code. However, what you are asking unfortunately is unclear to me. It would help if you could define what you expect as the result of "keeping divided unsorted data".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. At the code we have to divide the array into two arrays, which are unsorted. The first array is the left array and the second array is the right array. Then split the left and the right arrays into two arrays each. And finally keep splitting until the arrays have only one element each (these arrays are unsorted). I meant that final singular elements.

Comment: This appears to be a coursework question (against StackOverflow policy), so I can only hint:
1. Where do you think the actual sorting takes place?
2. Where is the case handled at which point you are left with a singular element?
Answering those questions should hopefully lead you to your answer.

Comment: I'am just trying to understand a piece of code and I just want to know that when it will hit the merge method, after finishing two mergeSort methods or every cycle of two recursive calls?

Comment: @rcgldr As far as I understand after two recursion, mergeSort method calls merge method 8 times with different start, mid and end values through the stack, is it correct?

Comment: @paperring - I posted an answer showing the order. There are 6 calls to merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ ] to indicate splits, | | for single runs, { } for merged runs. This is the order:

```
                                        level of recursion
[ 20   35  -15    7   55    1  -22]     0
[ 20   35  -15]                         1
| 20|                                   2
     [ 35  -15]                         2
     | 35|                              3
          |-15|                         3
     {-15   35}                         2
{-15   20   35}                         1
               [  7   55    1  -22]     1
               [  7   55]               2
               |  7|                    3
                    | 55|               3
               {  7   55}               2
                         [  1  -22]     2
                         |  1|          3
                              |-22|     3
                         {-22    1}     2
               {-22    1    7   55}     1
{-22  -15    1    7   20   35   55}     0
```

Comment: It might help to illustrate this by finding some animation for the algorithm online.

Comment: @Zabuza - I haven't found one yet that shows the ordering of all steps for top down. The wiki article shows the splitting in parallel, which doesn't correspond to top down or bottom up.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you for this amazing response, that's very helpful.